# Letter sequence - B, D, H, P,?

Tags: sequence, letter-sequence

Complete the sequence B - D - H - P _:
a. F
b. M
c. V
d. Z
e. None of the above is correct.
[Source](https://www.amazon.com.br/Fundamentos-Matem%C3%A1tica-Elementar-Gelson-Samuel/dp/853571748X/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_pt_BR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=Fundamentos+de+matem%C3%A1tica+elementar+-+Volume+4%3A+Sequ%C3%AAncias%2C+matrizes%2C+determiante&qid=1609724403&sr=8-1)

I tried to build a sequence based on the distance between the letters, but I didn't get anything relevant.
B - D - H - P _
1, 3, 6, ...

Comment: Could you please tell us exactly where in that book this question appears, and in what context? (E.g., if it's in the exercises at the end of a chapter, what's the chapter about?) Thank you.

Comment: The book, for reference, is "Handbook of Codes and Sequences with Applications in Communication, Computing and Information Security", in Chapman & Hall's series on "Discrete Mathematics and its Applications", and the publication date given by Amazon is three years from now.

Comment: And your link is to a page you reach specifically by searching amazon.com.br for "sequences matemhatics".

Comment: I take the questions out of several books, often with similar names. So these recurring errors ... I apologize :(

Comment: Sorry, I don't believe you.

Comment: It is _extremely clear_ that you are attempting to cheat on IQ-test-type questions that someone is setting you, and just searching for books whose titles make it sound a little bit as if they might have the questions in. They are not your real sources, and you are lying to us. This is not acceptable here.

Comment: Puzzling Stack Exchange is not intended as a resource for cheating on IQ tests.

Comment: If you post any further such questions where the "source" you reference doesn't _enable us to verify_ that it is the source of your question, we will assume that you are lying again and take appropriate action.

Comment: This is a serious charge. I am not doing this, not least because these tests are mostly in person. As I keep several tabs open in the PDF reader, I search for the subject name to try to find the book I'm using. I often get confused (how many books with "discrete math" in the title do you know, for example?). But ok ... I understand the suspicion.

Comment: Well, if you want us to believe you, henceforth you will have to provide some evidence.

Comment: Got it. Are the book, page and question sufficient?

Comment: Only if there is a way for us to _verify_ that the book contains what you say it does. I do not have a copy of, for instance, the "Handbook of Codes and Sequences ..." (although I am _very very confident_ that it does not contain any questions of remotely the type you have been asking here) and I am not going to go and buy one to check whether your question really comes from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is most possibly

> a. F

because

> if you convert A, B, C, ... into 1, 2, 3, ..., then you get B = 2, D = 4, H = 8, P = 16. The simplest way to describe this pattern is that they are powers of 2, so the next value must be 32. Since we have only 26 letters in the alphabet, we count the letters in cycles to get the letter F. (Alternatively, if you know modular arithmetic, you can get F by 32 mod 26 = 6.)